# Using ssl port with IIS authentication and api

Tags: iis, authentication

We have a asp.net web app and associated self-hosted nancy rest API. Currently the web app is secure over ssl and the api is not on port 80 (still under development).

IIS authentication is on and redirects unauthorised requests to the user login page.

In an ideal world I would like nancy to also be on port 443.

But this means that IIS redirects any traffic on port 443 to the user login page.

Is it possible to have application/json requests rewritten to go to nancy prior to IIS authentication redirection? Or any paths that begin with /api/

How can I get IIS authentication and nancy to play nice with the same port?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't use Nancy, so I'm not sure this helps, but:

You can enable IIS authentication selectively, for just certain parts of your site, or excluding a certain route.

In your web.config you can have something like this:

```
<location path="/api/">    
    <system.webServer>
      <security>
          <authentication>
              <basicAuthentication enabled="false"/>
              <anonymousAuthentication enabled="true" />
          </authentication>
      </security>
  </system.webServer>  
</location>
```

Using the `location` node, you can define which parts of your site should use different types of authentication.

You could then still use the URL Rewrite module to re-write URLs based on their MIME types.

Comment: this looks like the solution.  I will have a play and get you a green tick if it works.